# BigQuery - how to list all views and tables that use same UDF?

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Not sure where I can check the UDF I am using is used by which tables and Tableau views

Answer (score 0):

If the connection to Tableau is managed by a service account you could check the logs filtered on the queries that are being ran by said service account. Then you should be able to filter by certain UDF names from your project.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#default_project_in_sql_expressions